# JS: how to host an iOS touchmove game with no address bar and no pinch zoom

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, fullscreen, mobile-website

This is proving very difficult to research, though if I search an hour or so can probably find the answer. If anyone can beat me to it, I would love to know.

I'm live coding with **[jsbin.org](http://jsbin.org)**, and want to view my output html and drag my fingers around without causing the address bar to move, without having the window zoom.

I haven't tried `.preventDefault()` or researching CSS but those are possibilities too. Anyone with experience, would love to know how you solve this problem, aside from learning XCode and creating a UIWebView myself.......

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the address bar might be impossible, for obvious reasons, and iOS can't requestFullscreen

**Prevent pinch zoom:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
```

**Prevent movable viewport:**

`event.preventDefault()` inside a `touchstart` callback